# Forward network packets from host machine to QEMU image

Tags: networking, qemu, tcp, port-forwarding, tunneling

I have got a locally built Yocto image with me running inside QEMU. I need to forward a single port from the host machine to `localhost` inside the QEMU image. The TAP connection I am using assigns `192.168.7.1` to the host machine, `192.168.7.2` to the QEMU image.

I start a server on the host machine which the QEMU image is successfully able to `wget` to. An example of how it looks like in the QEMU image :-
[image: QEMU image wget snapshot]

The app which I want to run in the QEMU image talks to `127.0.0.1` not `192.168.7.1` on port `5000`. How do I tunnel this port (`5000`) in the external IP (`192.168.7.1`) to localhost? A small diagram of what I want:-
[image: iptables]

### PS Note:

The following this I have tried:

#### iptables

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 5000 -i eth0 -j DNAT --to-destination   127.0.0.1:5000
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --sport 5001 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.7.1:5001
```

[image: iptables]

#### ssh-tunneling

```
ssh -f -N osboxes@192.168.7.1 -L 5000:localhost:5001
```

(Here `osboxes` is the hostname of the host machine)
[image: ssh-tunneling]

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author of the question here. The answer to this is to use a [slirp connection](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Networking#User_Networking_.28SLIRP.29).
Using networking tools like `xinetd`, `iptables`, `sshd` show themselves as working - but weren't in my case. After exhaustively going through each of those configurations I saw I was just making my job tougher by bringing in a new NIC from a tap connection.

Using slirp networking flags is way easier if networking is to be done with the emulated OS's localhost. QEMU flags which worked for me are:

```
-netdev user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp::5000-:5000,hostfwd=tcp::5001-:5001
```